# Obtain column index of start of strings in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have legacy text files with lines as follows

```
John Deer              Works in College
Alex H Johnson         Hobby is painting
David Martin Smith     Runs everyday to keep fit
```

The first column are names and the second column is description. In this example the description column starts from column 23 of each line. There are plenty of such text files and every file has a different column number from which the description starts. There is no way to differentiate (programmatically) between name and description.
For a particular text file, I want to find the column number from which the description starts. This is so that I can insert details about a person in the files and the formatting is maintained.
Is there a way to find this column number for each text file? or any other way to add a new name-description entry so that the formatting is maintained.

**Edit:** From the suggested answers, I implemented the following code to add a new entry to the existing text files

```
with open (filename, 'r') as fr:
    descPos = []
    for line in fr:
        pos = line.rfind('    ')    #4 spaces
        if pos != -1:
            pos += 4
            descPos.append(pos)

descColumn = max(descPos, key = descPos.count)  #The mode of descPos values will be the column position where description starts
spacesBetweenNameAndDesc = descColumn - len(name)
newEntry = name + ' '*spacesBetweenNameAndDesc + desc

with open(file, 'w') as fw:
    fw.write(newEntry)
```

Here `"name"` and `"desc"` are the new name and description that is to be appended.
Is this the best way to add a new entry while maintaining the formatting?

Comment: If columns are separated by two or more spaces and the normal text by just one, this should do it!

Comment: Why not read the file and split by space? What have you tried so far?You can also use regex to find the starting position of description but not very clear unless we see your attempt and expected output

Comment: check whether what looks like spaces between the colums are actually spaces or tabs - if those are tabs then you don't have to care about index, just split on the tabs (or use the csv modules - it knows how parse tab-separated values too).

Comment: From the comments I am getting the idea to find the number of spaces between words in each line. Then find the words that have the maximum number of spaces between them. One of them is the starting word for the description. Then find the index of that word.

Comment: @tonypdmtr for names which are long, the number of spaces between name and description can be one

Comment: If that's the case, unless you have some way of identifying the names, you're probably out of luck. In that case, then I think the most useful thing to do is manually "counting" the characters before the category inside of a loop, and using that variable for each file.

And by "counting" I mean just copying, and pasting all of the characters before into a `input`-field and doing a `len()` on it.

Comment: @ontherocks You can still guess the column if at least one row has more than one space between name and description.

Comment: @tonypdmtr yeh, that's what I just thought too. I read line by line and take one which has a high number of spaces between two consecutive words.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer the question in the best possible manner. Not sure why you need index of the second column but let's say you need it then below code will provide the way to get the index as well as getting the string as `list` of string

```
import re

temp="""
John Deer              Works in College
Alex H Johnson         Hobby is painting
David Martin Smith     Runs everyday to keep fit"""

for line in temp.split("\n"):
    m =re.finditer('\s{2,}\w',line)
    for i in m:
        print(i.end()-1) # gives you the columns index ignoring the first column

    lis = re.sub("\s{2,}",'\t',line).split("\t")
    if lis !=['']:
        print(lis)
```

Just for the completeness you can also use pandas to format your data along with StringIO. Below is the example to create a dataframe

```
import sys
import re
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
temp="""
John Deer              Works in College
Alex H Johnson         Hobby is painting
David Martin Smith     Runs everyday to keep fit"""

TESTDATA = StringIO(re.sub('\s{2,}','\t',temp))

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep="\t",names=['Names','Description'])
```

Comment: I wanted to get the index so that when I insert a new line with a name and description, I know where to add the description so that the formatting is maintained.  If there are other ways, I will be glad to know.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to obtain the position of the first *word* character in the line following at least 2 whitespace characters.

```
with open(filename) as fd:
    rx = re.compile(r'(?<=\s\s)\w+')
    # search if first 5 lines
    ix = max((rx.search(line).start() for line in itertools.islice(fd, 5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility which will work provided (a) at least one line in your input file has at least two spaces between columns, (b) column text has no more than single spaces, and (c) same file columns are aligned:

```
def get_description_position(filename):
  with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
      pos = line.rfind('  ')+2          #-1 if not found
      if pos > 1: return pos            #return as soon as a row matches
  raise Exception('Could not find description column')

################################################################################

filename = '56259699.txt'               #whatever your input filename

################################################################################

try: col = get_description_position(filename)
except Exception as msg: print(msg)
else:
  with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
      name, desc = line[:col].strip(),line[col:].strip()
      print(f'{name:20s} {desc}')
```

Comment: I used this to implement addition of new entry to the file without losing formatting. Let me know if there was any better way to code it.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a little vague and you don't have any example coding, so this may be a shot in the dark.

Anyway, you can do this really easily in pandas, by taking your file and turning it into a pandas dataframe, using read_csv, read_excel, or whatever.

As I understand it, you want to take two columns out of a larger set, as a new dataframe.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
df = pd.read_excel('your_file_here.xlsx')
name_description_df = df[['Name', 'Description']]
```

Does that answer your question? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: While I agree that the wording of his question isn't very sufficient, what I am sure about is that the file he's referring to is probably not either a .csv- or .xlsx-file. If he was working with one of those files, then he wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: This is a vague answer to a vague question. Assuming file is a text file this will certainly fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can split each line in 2 strings and then search for the index of the first character in the second string.

As an example:

`x = "John Deer              Works in College"`

Using the [`str.split` method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
y = x.split("  ", maxsplit=1) #['John Deer', '            Works in College']
```

Then use the [str.strip method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to get rid of the leading spaces (note the double space in the method argument):

```
z = y.strip('  ') #'Works in College'
character = z[0]  #'W'
```

Now you find the index using the str.find method:

```
index = len(y[0]) + y[1].find(character) +2  #23
```

The `+2` added corresponds to the removed substring `"  "` when splitting the original one.

Having said that I encourage you to use a standard format such as `.csv` or `.json`. Doing this you will be able to easily parse it using a single method in many libraries.